# how to use QtSingleApplication bt the so file?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I need to use QtSingleApplication in my Qt application. I didn't understand from the documentation how to use the add on by the so file.
can you please help me? (step by step)

thanks!

Comment: What didn't you understand? Documentation seems to be detailed. Maybe you can explain in your question what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty straightforward, put the following in main.cpp:

```
#include <QtSingleApplication>
#include <QWidget>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QtSingleApplication app(argc, argv);

  // if application is running, we terminate it
  if (app.isRunning())
    return 0;

  // application wasn't running, so we go on with our lives
  QWidget w;
  app.setActivationWindow(&w);
  w.show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

and in project's .pro file:

```
INCLUDE += -I/usr/local/include
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lQtSingleApplication
```

and then perform the usual drill:

```
qmake
make
```